# How can I export my public GnuPG keychain into one block?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

I'd like to send my entire public keychain to a friend of mine (and back it up for obvious reasons) and would like to export it into one single block, like GPA does. Bonus points if it's signed with my own private key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gpg --export` without further filters exports *all* public keys including signatures. Apply the `--armor` option if you want ASCII-armored output, and redirect output to a file. This command line exports all public keys to the `public-keys.gpg` file in the ASCII-armored format:

```
gpg --armor --export > public-keys.gpg
```

It can be imported using the usual `gpg --import public-keys.gpg` command.

Before GnuPG 2.1, you can also simply send the `~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg` file, but this also includes "local" signatures that usually should not be exported. Since GnuPG 2.1 this is not possible any more, since the file also contains the private keys, and it is possible the keyring is in the keybox format instead (`pubring.kbx`).

If you want the file signed, you have to do this in a second step, like you would sign any other file:

```
gpg --sign public-keys.gpg
```